# How to integrate the infinitesimal spacetime interval?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, integration

Consider events A and B with coordinates $(t_A,x_A,y_A,z_A)$ and $(t_B,x_B,y_B,z_B)$ respectively.

The spacetime interval $\Delta s$ between them is given by $$\Delta s= \sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2-\Delta y^2-\Delta z^2}$$
where $\Delta t=t_B-t_A$ etc.

I am trying to prove that the spacetime interval $\Delta s$ can also be found by integrating the  infinitesimal spacetime interval $ds$ using 
$$\Delta s=\int^B_A ds$$
where  $ds$ is given by
$$ds = \sqrt{c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2}.$$

So I will have to integrate 
$$\int^B_A ds = \int^B_A \sqrt{c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2}.$$

How can this be integrated to show that $\int^B_A ds = \Delta s$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generically, it isn't.  $\int_A^B ds$ is the proper time elapsed along the worldline connecting $A$ and $B$, and its value depends very much on which worldline you choose.  The $\Delta s$ you mention is the proper time along the *straight line* connecting the events, meaning that it is the proper time as measured by an inertial observer traveling between them.

Explicitly, let $x,y,$ and $z$ be functions of $t$.  We then have

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}c\sqrt{1 - \frac{\dot x^2 - \dot y^2 - \dot z^2}{c^2}} dt$$

To go further, you need to specify what the functions $x,y,$ and $z$ are.  In the simplest case, (that of constant velocity), one could have

$$ x(t) = x_i + \frac{(x_f - x_i)}{t_f-t_i} t =x_i +\overline v_x t$$
$$ y(t) = y_i + \overline v_y t $$
$$ z(t) = z_1 + \overline v_z t $$
from there, the integral becomes

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f} c\sqrt{1-\frac{\overline v_x^2 + \overline v_y^2 + \overline v_z^2}{c^2}} dt = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} c\sqrt{1-\frac{\overline v^2}{c^2}} dt = c\Delta t \sqrt{1-\frac{\overline v^2}{c^2}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ c^2\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2 - \Delta z^2}$$

However, if you choose a different worldline connecting $A$ and $B$, this will no longer be true.  As a good exercise, you might try the worldline you get by traveling at constant speed $2\overline v$ for half the time (assuming that $\overline v < c/2$, of course), and then sitting still for the remainder.  This is not the worldline of an inertial observer, so we would expect the corresponding proper time to be smaller than before; indeed, you should find that

$$\Delta s=c \frac{\Delta t}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{4\overline v^2}{c^2}} + c \frac{\Delta t}{2}$$
$$ = \sqrt{\frac{c^2\Delta t^2}{4} - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2 - \Delta z^2} + \frac{c \Delta t^2}{2} < \sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y ^2 - \Delta z^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is essentially @J. Murray's answer, rewritten in a way I find easier to understand.*

The quantity $\int^B_A ds$ depends on the worldine connecting events A and B, i.e. the path taken by the particle in spacetime.

$\int^B_A ds = \Delta s = \sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2-\Delta y^2-\Delta z^2}$ is only true when worldline is a straight line, i.e. the particle travels at constant velocity.

[image]

Consider a 2D case as shown in this diagram, where the  infinitesimal spacetime interval is given by $ds^2=c^2dt^2-dx^2.$

The equation for the straight worldline connecting events A and B is 
$$ct=\frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x}x.$$
This gives the differential relation $$dt=\frac{(\Delta t)}{\Delta x}dx.$$
The quantity $\int^B_A ds$ can now be calculated by
$$\int^B_A ds = \int^B_A \sqrt{c^2dt^2-dx^2} =\int^B_A  \sqrt{c^2\frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta x^2}dx^2-dx^2}=\int^B_A dx\sqrt{c^2\frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta x^2}-1} =\Delta x \sqrt{c^2\frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta x^2}-1} =\sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2}.$$

This shows that $\int^B_Ads = \sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2}$ is true for a straight worldine in the 2D case. This result can be generalised to the 4D case.

If the quantity  $\int^B_Ads$ was calculated for the curly dotted worldline shown  in the diagram, $\int^B_Ads$  in general will not be equal to $ \sqrt{c^2\Delta t^2-\Delta x^2}$.

Comment: Looks good to me.  The only note I'll make is that you say the dotted wordline will generally not correspond to the same proper time.  I would make this claim stronger - the dotted worldline will correspond to a *strictly smaller* proper time, because in Minkowski spacetime, straight worldlines correspond to the maximum possible proper time between events (incidentally, this is the proper resolution to the twin paradox).